# Save image (via ImageWriter / FileImageOutputStream) to the filesystem without use of a File object

Tags: java-8, javax.imageio

As a learning task I am converting my software I use every day to NIO, with the somewhat arbitrary objective of having zero remaining instances of `java.io.File`.

I have been successful in every case except one.  It seems an `ImageWriter` can only write to a `FileImageOutputStream` which requires a `java.io.File`.

```
Path path = Paths.get(inputFileName);
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);

    ...

Iterator<ImageWriter> iter =   ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
ImageWriter writer = iter.next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
ImageOutputStream ios = new FileImageOutputStream(outputFile);
IIOImage iioi = new IIOImage(bi, null, null);

writer.setOutput(ios);
writer.write(null, iioi, param);

...
```

Is there a way to do this with a `java.nio.file.Path`?  The java 8 api doc for `ImageWriter` only mentions `FileImageOutputStream`.

I understand there might only be a symbolic value to doing this, but I was under the impression that NIO is intended to provide a *complete* alternative to `java.io.File`.

Answer (score 0):

A `RandomAccessFile`, [constructed with just a String for a filename](http://xahlee.info/java8_doc/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), can be supplied to the [ImageOutputStream constructor](http://xahlee.info/java8_doc/api/javax/imageio/stream/FileImageOutputStream.html) constructor.

This doesn't "use NIO" any more than just using the `File` in the first place, but it doesn't require File to be used directly..

For direct support of `Path` (or to "use NIO"), the FileImageOutputStream (or RandomAccessFile) could be extended, or a type deriving from the ImageOutputStream interface created, but .. how much work is it worth?

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to instantiate an `ImageInputStream` or `ImageOutputStream` in the `javax.imageio` API, is through the `ImageIO.createImageInputStream()` and `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream()` methods.

You will see that both these methods take `Object` as its parameter. Internally, `ImageIO` will use a service lookup mechanism, and delegate the creation to a provider able to create a stream based on the parameter. By default, there are providers for `File`, `RandomAccessFile` and `InputStream`.

But the mechanism is extendable. See the [API doc for the `javax.imageio.spi` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/package-summary.html) for a starting point. If you like, you can create a provider that takes a `java.nio.Path` and creates a `FileImageOutputStream` based on it, or alternatively create your own implementation using some more fancy NIO backing (ie. `SeekableByteChannel`).

Here's source code for a sample [provider](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-core/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/stream/ByteArrayImageInputStreamSpi.java) and [stream](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-core/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/stream/ByteArrayImageInputStream.java) I created to read images from a `byte` array, that you could use as a starting point.

(Of course, I have to agree with @user2864740's thoughts on the cost/benefit of doing this, but as you are doing this for the sake of learning, it might make sense.)

Comment: If `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream()` accepts an `OutputStream`, you can use [`Channels.newOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newOutputStream-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-) to convert the channel created for a `Path` to an `OutputStream`. If the `Path` represents a path in the default filesystem, hence the channel is a `FileChannel`, the output stream will be a `FileOutputStream` though. But you don’t have to deal with neither `File` nor `FileOutputStream` manually…

Comment: @Holger Good point! However, I try to avoid using the `InputStream`/`OutputStream` based implementations, as they are usually slower.  These `ImageInput/OutputStream` implementations have to do caching of the stream contents to allow backwards seeks. By default this caching uses disk cache...